# Show $[K : F] = [K : E][E : F]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let $E\subset F\subset K$ be fields. Show that if $K$ is a field extension of finite degree over $F$ and $F$ is a field extension of finite degree over $E$ then $[K : E] = [K : F][F : E]$.

---

Since $F$ is a vector space over $E$ with degree $m$ and $K$ is a vector space over $F$ with degree $n$, then $K$ is a vector space over $F$. So $[K : E] = [K : F][F : E]=mn$.

---

I think I still miss some details need to show. Can anyone tell me what they are? Thanks!

Comment: Since $[K : E] = m$, then $K$ is a vector space over $E$ with dimension $m$. So there's some $E$-basis for $K$ with $m$ elements. Similarly, there's an $F$-basis for $E$, with $n$ elements. Can you construct a $F$-basis for $K$? How many elements should it have?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78517/given-fields-m-e-f-why-does-mf-meef/78521#78521

Answer (score 3):

Just use your bases.

Let $\{f_i\},\{k_j\}$ be bases for $F/E, K/F$ respectively. Then if $k\in K$ we have $c_{ij}\in E$ so that

> $$k=\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\sum_{i=1}^m c_{ij}f_i\right)k_j$$

Then the coordinate mapping gives the dimension as $mn$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $[K:E]=m$ and $[E:F]=n.$ Let $\{u_1,\ldots,u_m \} \subseteq K$ be a basis of $K$ over $F$ and let $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n \} \subseteq F$ be a basis of $F$ over $E.$ Consider the subset $\Big\{u_i v_j:i=1,\ldots,m, \hspace{1mm} j = 1,\ldots,n \Big\} \subseteq K.$ We need to prove that this subset is linearly independent and spans $K.$ Let $x \in K.$ (What comes next? Hint: Express $x$ as a linear combination of vectors in $K$ and scalars in $F.)$

> Then $x$ of the form $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^m a_i u_i$ where $a_i \in F, \hspace{1mm} u_i \in K.$ We may write $a_i = \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} v_j$ where $a_{ij} \in E, \hspace{1mm} v_j \in F.$ It follows that $x = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}u_i v_j$ and so the elements $u_i v_j$ span all of $K$ over $E.$

The subset is also linearly independent because (Hint: Set an element of $K$ equal to $0$ and then use the fact that the basis vectors are linear independent)

> $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}u_i v_j = 0, \hspace{1mm} a_{ij} \in E \Longrightarrow \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^m \left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} v_j \right)_{\in F} u_i = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} v_j = 0  \Longleftrightarrow a_{ij} = 0$ for every $i,j$ since the $u_i$ are linearly independent over $F$ and the $v_j$ are linearly independent over $E.$

Therefore $\Big\{u_i v_j:i=1,\ldots,m, \hspace{1mm} j = 1,\ldots,n \Big\} \subseteq K$ is a basis of $K$ over $E$ and $[K:F] = mn = [K:E][E:F]. \Box$

Comment: Sadly, your answer leaves nothing for the asker to try.

Comment: @user21820 You're right, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'proof' is begging the question. The 'fact' you use does not even make sense for vector spaces because the intermediate vector space may not be a field and so it would be meaningless to talk about dimension (not "degree") of the biggest over it. For fields it happens to be true, but to prove it you literally have to show that you can find a basis for the biggest over the smallest that is of the correct size, meaning that it spans and is linearly independent. What do you think would be a basis?